# How do I get this script to delete zero-length files in the current directory and subdirectories without using find?

Tags: bash

I want my script to delete all zero length files in the directory that is shown as an argument as well as all of the zero length files in the sub directory.

I wrote a script that can delete all of the zero length files in the current directory. I need it to be able to enter sub directories and delete those zero length files too.

What can I do to solve this problem?

```
DIR=$1
TRAV= touch -c "$DIR"/*

for d in ./$(DIR)/*; do
        if [ -f "${d}" ] && [ -s "${d}" ]; then
                echo "$d has some data"
        else
                echo "$d has no data, we're deleting it."
                rm -d -R ${d}
        fi
done
```

~                                                                                                                                                            ~                                                                                                                                                            ~

The program works perfectly fine so far, it just doesn't delete the zero length files in the sub directories of the specified directory.

Comment: You're looking for `globstar`

Comment: Sir, you may not know it, but you just saved the day.

Comment: To be fair, I did. Multiple times, I wasn't aware this kind of tool existed until this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add shopt -s globstar to the script to enable globstar, change line four

from

```
for d in ./$(DIR)/*; do
```

to

```
for d in ./$(DIR)/**/*; do
```

then run the script with your directory as an argument

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use "find"?
If you don't use "find", you can do by using a recursive call and ls command instead.

```
#!/bin/bash
function del(){
    local dir=$1
    cd ${dir}
    for f in $(ls -1)
    do
        if [ -d "${f}" ]; then
            (del ${f})
        else
            if [ ! -s ${f} ]; then
                rm -f ${f}
            fi
        fi
    done
}
del .
```

Comment: Use of 'find' was prohibited by my professor, and for good reason, this actually helps.

Comment: If this answer helped you, I would be glad if you pushed the "This answer is useful" button.

Comment: No, this answer didn't help me I was referring to my professor issuing the challenge of making me write without using find.